# Show that $\left\| f \right\|_r$ is continuous function in $r$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove a statement below.

If $f\in L^1(0,\infty)\cap L^2(0,\infty)$ then

$\left\| f \right\|_r$ is continuous function in $r$ on $[1,2]$.

I just proved that $f\in L^r(0,\infty)$ $\forall r\in (1,2)$  but don't know how to prove the continuity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $|f_n| \leq |f|$ almost everywhere for each $n$. Then $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ as well as $L^{2}$. Claim: $\|f_n - f\|_r\to 0$ uniformly for $1 \leq r \leq 2$.  Let $g_n=f_n-f$. Then $$\int |g_n|^{r} =\int_{|g_n| \leq 1} |g_n|^{r}   +\int_{|g_n| > 1} |g_n|^{r} \leq \int |g_n|+\int |g_n|^{2} \to 0.$$ This proves the claim. It is trivial to check that $\|h\|_r$ is a continuous function of $r$ when $h$ is simple. By uniform convergence the same is true for the given $f$.

Comment: I cannot see if it is true when $h$ is simple and the measure is not finite. Could you clarify more?

Comment: @LevBan You are dealing with a  simple function that belongs to $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$.  So it is of the type $\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k I_{E_{k}}$ where each $E_{k}$ has finite measure.

Comment: @LevBan $(\sum_{k=1}^{N} |a_k|^{r}m(E_k))^{1/r}$ is certainly  a continuous function of $r$ if $m(E_k) <\infty$ for all $k$, right?